# Problema con método Update de un Controller utilizando Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Quiero hacer un `Update` en una tabla, estoy utilizando el siguente metodo en un controller:

```php
public function update(DeviceModelStore $request, DeviceModel $deviceModel)
    {
        // dd($deviceModel);
        $deviceModel->update($request->all());
        return new DeviceModelResource($deviceModel);
    }
```

Este código no funciona, me parece que tengo algun problema con `DeviceModel`.

Si descomento `dd($deviceModel)` obtengo el siguente `debugging`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan aparecen muchos datos como `null`: connection, y table por ejemplo, ademas de no traer la informacion que tiene.
Yo ya probe agregar en `DeviceModel` el siguente código, pero sigue sin funcionar.

```php
protected $table = 'device_models';
protected $connection = 'mysql';
```

Por otro lado, estoy utilizando `Postman` para probar los EntryPoint, y cuando ingreso en la ruta un `id` que no existe, no me arroja un 404. Exista o no exista el recurso, siempre me devuelve el siguente `json`

```json
{
    "data": {
        "id": null,
        "name": null
    }
}
```

Esta misma practica la estoy aplicando con otro `Model/Table` y no tengo ningun problema.

La unica diferencia que tengo con otro `Model` es la forma que estan nombrados: los otros modelos solamente tienen una letra mayúscula, este tiene dos, debido a que quiero hacer referencia a 'Modelos de dispositivos'

**¿Cual puede ser el problema? **

Aca les muestro como tengo `DeviceModel`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Mark;
use App\Models\DeviceType;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class DeviceModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'mark_id',
        'device_type_id'
    ];

    public function mark()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Mark::class);
    }

    public function deviceType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DeviceType::class);
    }
}
```

Detalle de las rutas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, es simplemente para validar que el campo name sea requerido. Probe usar Request de `Illuminate\Http\Client\Request` y sigue con el mismo problema.

Comment: Al agregar un modelo como parámetro en tu método se buscará por id, agregaste el campo `protected $primaryKey = '...'` en tu modelo? Claro, que eso sólo será necesario si tu tabla no sigue los lineamientos de Laravel.

Comment: No, porque no es necesario en mi caso, el primary key es `id`

Comment: Porque cuando debugeo $deviceModel no aparece el tipo de conexion (mysql) ni tampoco la tabla (device_models)?

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos la ruta que tienes para este método update?

Comment: Es una apiResource

Route::apiResource('admin/devicemodel', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DeviceModelController::class)->middleware('auth:api');

ahi agregue una captura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente tienes un problema de `binding` con los parámetros de tu ruta.

Hacer lo siguiente solucionaría tu problema:

```
public function update(DeviceModelStore $request, DeviceModel $devicemodel)
{
    dd($devicemodel->name);
}
```

El cambio es simple, de `$deviceModel` a `$devicemodel` como parámetro en tu método.

Comment: Increible, pero funciono! A que se debe este problema, no logro entenderlo, porque de esta u la otra manera esta llamando al modelo correcto. Jamas se me ubiera ocurrido hacer este cambio, ya que en todo el controller lo estoy nombrando asi.

Comment: El nombre del parámetro debe hacer match con el que tienes en el controlador, puedes leer al respecto [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding)